# How to fix 'RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0' in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'note_details.dart';
import '../database_helper.dart';
import '../Note.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class NoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NoteListState createState() => _NoteListState();
}

class _NoteListState extends State<NoteList> {
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper =  DatabaseHelper();
  List<Note> noteList;  
  int count=0;

  void navigateToDetail(Note note, String title) async{
    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
      return NoteDetails(note, title);
    }));
    if (result ==  true){
      updateListView();   
    }
  }

  //get the noteList view
  ListView getNoteListView(){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (context,position){
        return Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          color: Color(0xff1D1D1D),
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage("http://learncodeonline.in/mascot.png") ,
            ),
            title: Text(this.noteList[position].title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0),),
            subtitle: Text(this.noteList[position].date, style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffBB86FC)) ,),
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new, color: Color(0xffBB86FC)),
              onTap: (){
                navigateToDetail(this.noteList[position], "Edit Possible");
              }
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }


  void updateListView(){
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    dbFuture.then((database){
      Future<List<Note>> noteListFuture = databaseHelper.getNoteList();
      noteListFuture.then((noteList){
        setState(() {
          this.noteList = noteList;
          this.count = noteList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  } 


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(noteList!=null){
      noteList = List<Note>();
      updateListView();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('What TODO:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff1f1f1f),
          centerTitle: false,
        ),
      body: getNoteListView(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffBB86FC),
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_comment, color: Colors.black,),
        label: Text("TODO: ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
        elevation: 5.0,
        // foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: (){
          navigateToDetail(Note('','',2), 'Add Note');
        },
      ),  
    );`
  }
}
```

There are two pages in this app. One of it is a view with list of all the TODO's and the other is the page where we mention the TODO's. Entry in the database can be successfully done but once added it the list view shows the mentioned error.

the list view page which list down all the Todos from the database. One a TODO is added from the details page it pops back to this (view page). But it then shows the error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

Comment: So your `getNoteListView()` is the one causing errors? After you add a new Note to your details page is that right?

Comment: Yes I guess that is where the error is occuring.

Comment: Alright perhaps you can add a `print(count)` and `print(position)` right before the `return Card()` statement and we could work our way from there. Cause most likely you have an extra card at the end (being added to the db) but some stuff are not updating (perhaps your list) or something like that.

Comment: the count is increasing constantly from 3 to 4 .. but the position remains 0

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The position is supposed to be the index which auto-increments. Why would it stay at 0?

Comment: No idea where i have gone wrong

Comment: I've tried running your code but I'm not able to replicate it due to some missing parts like the *Note.dar*t. Could you provide for [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of *Note.dart*? Also, could you confirm if these are the codes you've used for [*note_details.dart*](https://github.com/smartherd/Flutter-Demos/blob/master/lib/screens/note_detail.dart) and [*database_helper.dart*](https://github.com/smartherd/Flutter-Demos/blob/master/lib/utils/database_helper.dart)?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the previous discussion, it looks like `count` gets updated its value. The reason you're still getting the error is because `getNoteListView()` is still called, attempting to create a `ListView` from an empty `noteList`. What you can do here is only generate a ListView  if the `noteList` length is greater than 0. Else, display a different Widget (i.e. CircularProgressIndicator)

```dart
body: (noteList.length > 0) ? getNoteListView() : CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

and use noteList.length for `ListView.builder()` itemCount

```dart
ListView getNoteListView(){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: noteList.length,
    ...
  );
}
```

Though the best solution here is by using either `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` to run the request to populate `noteList` prior to building the `ListView` widget.